# Where is file that creates human character generated from?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was just messing around with the following three.js example **[HERE](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals)** ,  saw the following piece of code in the example , see below:

```
function loadLeePerrySmith( callback ) {

            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

            loader.load( 'obj/leeperrysmith/LeePerrySmith.js', function( geometry ) {

                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    specular: 0x111111,
                    map: textureLoader.load( 'obj/leeperrysmith/Map-COL.jpg' ),
                    specularMap: textureLoader.load( 'obj/leeperrysmith/Map-SPEC.jpg' ),
                    normalMap: textureLoader.load( 'obj/leeperrysmith/Infinite-Level_02_Tangent_SmoothUV.jpg' ),
                    normalScale: new THREE.Vector2( 0.75, 0.75 ),
                    shininess: 25
                } );

                mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( mesh );
                mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );

                //scene.add( new THREE.FaceNormalsHelper( mesh, 1 ) );
                //scene.add( new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh, 1 ) );

            } );

        }
```

Now my question is about the `.js` file being loaded, I.E. the below file:

```
'obj/leeperrysmith/LeePerrySmith.js'
```

Now if i open i load this file it is quite a enormous file(**[SEE HERE](http://threejs.org/examples/obj/leeperrysmith/LeePerrySmith.js)**). What i really am interested is where really is this file created ? i mean is it created using some kind of a canvas tool, basically on inspection i realised in the example i have listed , this particular file is loading the person you can see on the screen.

I have worked a bit with SVG's and sometimes i use AI to generate complex SVGs , i was just wondering if this `.js` file was created in some kind of a tool or just to give me a general idea as to where exactly is this file coming from ?

P.S.: i know that asking for a resource if off topic but i am not asking for any resource, but merely asking you guys to give me an idea to where this JS file is being generated from.

Comment: Don't abuse backticks. They're to be used only for inline code snippets.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure sir  , i will try that in the future .

Comment: It says `"generatedBy": "OBJConverter"` right there in the meta data. At least [this converter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py) from the dupe'd answer generates that exact signature.

Comment: Data requested from a website can be generated many different ways.  Without access to the server itself, i.e. without an explicit knowledge of everything going on "behind the scenes", you really can't tell.  David Hedlund pointed out the best simple answer you can probably get!